# List<long> vs long[], memory usage

Tags: c#, .net, memory

Regarding the size in memory for the

```
List<long> ListOfLongs;
long[] ArrayOfLongs;
```

If each has N elements, how much memory they eat up?

I am asking that because as of my knowledge, .NET has not template (generics) specialization.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Practically the same amount of memory (technically, the `List` will probably consume some more because it has over-allocated so that it can grow more easily).

Generic collections in .NET do not need to box the items they hold, which would be a massive memory and performance sink.

Comment: You want to say that List<> is an array when it comes to implementation?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, a growable array.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: [Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx): *The List(Of T) class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class. It implements the IList(Of T) generic interface using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required.*

Comment: Very cool about the generic lists of value types -- I had always just assumed that they'd box their contents.  +1

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: What is there to comment about? [The intro to the namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) says *"...which allow users to create strongly typed collections that provide better type safety and performance than non-generic strongly typed collections."* Better performance *precisely because* they don't do boxing.

Comment: @Jon - if I have massive amount of List<long> objects, does it make any sense that I trim them after filling them with the data?

Comment: I deleted my answer... I assumed they are boxed, which seems to not be the case...

Comment: @DanielMošmondor List<T> is implemented as an array (T[]). You can easily check this by examining mscorlib.dll in Telerik JustDecompile or .NET Reflector.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: I don't know. Check the values of `Count` and `Capacity`, and if you think it's worth the massive reallocation call `TrimExcess`.

Answer (score 5):

The `List<T>` owns an array `T[]`. It uses an exponential growth strategy for this array, so a list with `n` elements usually has a backing array with size larger than `n`. Also the smaller arrays need to be garbage collected, which can be annoying if the are large enough to be on the LoH.

But you can avoid this by specifying a capacity manually, for example as a constructor parameter. Then a single array with the desired capacity will be allocated, so you avoid both of the above problems.

In addition `List<T>` has a small O(1) overhead for the list object itself.

---

But there is no per element overhead when using generics. The runtime creates a specialized version for each value type you pass in. No boxing of the elements occurs.

But you can't use C++ style template specialization, where you effectively overload the implementation for certain type parameters. All generic instantiations share the same C# code.

i.e. there is no specialized IL code, but each value type gets a specialized machine code implementation based on the same source-code.

Answer (score 1):

> I am asking that because as of my knowledge, .NET has not template (generics) specialization.

.Net doesn't have template specialization in the sense that you (as the programmer) can supply different code depending on the type arguments. But the compiler still can (and does) produce different code for value types than for reference type, i.e. (unlike in Java) value types are not boxed when put into a generic container. They're stored efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Using lists is more practical than using plain arrays. The key for performance and memory consumption is the Capacity of a list. By default it starts with a value of 4 and increases to 8, 16, 32, 64, ... whenever the elements of the list reach the defined capacity. Each increment is translated to an internal re-allocation and Array.Copy. So if you have a list with 1000 items and you expect 100 items in a day, you can instantiate the list with a capacity of 1200 (error margin in prediction 100%). This way you will avoid the re-allocation for 2000 items whenever you add the 10001 item, and of course the continuous re-allocations and Array.Copy to fill it with the existing 1000 items.